# Как ограничить нажатия в определенное время JS

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка переключения блоков, и есть эффект перехода. И мне нужно чтобы нельзя было нажимать на эту кнопку пока не пройдет некоторое время после нажатия. Иначе появляются ненужные визуальные баги. И кнопок 2, одно назад (`prev`), другое вперед (`next`)

```
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var activeBlock = document.querySelector('.content > .block.active');
    var nextBlock = activeBlock.nextElementSibling;

    if (nextBlock.classList.contains('block')) {
        nextBlock.classList.add('active', 'fadeIn');
        nextBlock.style.display = 'flex';
        setTimeout(function () {
        nextBlock.classList.remove('fadeIn');
            nextBlock.style.opacity = '1';
        }, 500);
    }
    else {
        firstBlock.classList.add('active', 'fadeIn');
        firstBlock.style.display = 'flex';
        setTimeout(function () {
            firstBlock.classList.remove('fadeIn');
            firstBlock.style.opacity = '1';
        }, 500);
    }

    activeBlock.classList.add('fadeOut');
    setTimeout(function () {
        activeBlock.classList.remove('fadeOut');
        activeBlock.classList.remove('active');
        activeBlock.style.opacity = '0';
        activeBlock.style.display = 'none';
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var timer = null;
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (timer)
    return;

  ...
  timer = setTimeout(function () {
    timer = null;
    activeBlock.classList.remove('fadeOut');
    activeBlock.classList.remove('active');
    activeBlock.style.opacity = '0';
    activeBlock.style.display = 'none';
  }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let isDisabled = false;

next.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(isDisabled) {
        return;
    }

    isDisabled = true;

    var activeBlock = document.querySelector('.content > .block.active');
    var nextBlock = activeBlock.nextElementSibling;

    if (nextBlock.classList.contains('block')) {
        nextBlock.classList.add('active', 'fadeIn');
        nextBlock.style.display = 'flex';
        setTimeout(function () {
            nextBlock.classList.remove('fadeIn');
            nextBlock.style.opacity = '1';
            isDisabled = false;
        }, 500);
    }
    else {
        firstBlock.classList.add('active', 'fadeIn');
        firstBlock.style.display = 'flex';
        setTimeout(function () {
            firstBlock.classList.remove('fadeIn');
            firstBlock.style.opacity = '1';
            isDisabled = false;
        }, 500);
    }

    activeBlock.classList.add('fadeOut');
    setTimeout(function () {
        activeBlock.classList.remove('fadeOut');
        activeBlock.classList.remove('active');
        activeBlock.style.opacity = '0';
        activeBlock.style.display = 'none';
        isDisabled = false;
    }, 500);
});
```